# Show $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, lebesgue-integral

It's claimed that $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$ by first expanding $\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$ into a power series and then doing term-by-term integration. I want to justify this by Levi's Theorem for Series, that is, if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of $L^1$ functions such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_X \lvert f_n\rvert \,\text{d}\mu \lt \infty$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n$ converges a.e. to an $L^1$ function $f$ such that $$\int_X \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f_k\text{d}\mu=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_Xf_k\,\text{d}\mu.$$ Note that we are focusing on Lebesgue integration, since the integrand is not defined at $x=0$ or $x=1$. I'm not sure how to show this, possibly by Taylor expansion? Could someone help to show to derive this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x&=&\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(-x)^n}{n} & \textrm{(Taylor series of }\ln(1+z))\\
&=& \int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x}\frac{(-1)(x^n)}{n}\\
&=& -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}\ \mathrm{d}x \\
&=&-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{x^n}{n^2}\right]_0^1 \\
&=&-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} \\
&=&-\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The last equality is the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) and requires a more complex approach.

Comment: It is important to note that in the third line of the equations Levi's theorem is used, so we can put the infinite sum outside of the integral. (The verification of the hypothesis in Levi's theorem is basically the last four lines)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be formal, the Taylor Expansion ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Examples)) $\log(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$ converges uniformly on sets of the form $[\epsilon,0]$.

So you can calculate
$$\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_\epsilon^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-\epsilon^n}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon^n}{n^2}.$$
where the last equality is well-known [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Now the integral on the LHS is simply the integral of $\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}\chi_{[\epsilon,1]}$ on $[0,1]$, where $\chi_{A}$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$. This converges pointwise, and in a decreasing way, to $\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$ on $(0,1]$, so (and all these functions are negative), so by [Monotone Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem), 
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon^n}{n^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
where the limit $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\epsilon^n}{n^2}=0$ can be calculated directly (for $\epsilon<1$, the terms in the sum are always smaller than $\epsilon/n^2$, so you can use the Basel problem again).

Answer (score 2):

This can be generalized as
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)^{n-1}}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)^{n-1}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{1-e^{-x}}\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-kx}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=(-1)^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^n}\int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[6pt]
&=(-1)^{n-1}\zeta(n)\,\Gamma(n)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
For $n=2$, this gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\zeta(2)\Gamma(2)\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}6\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

A more intuitive explanation, and the way to actually derive this integral (something I tried messing around with a while back) is to try long division of $\frac{1}{1-y}$. The motivation for this is to attempt a new solution at the *Basel problem*. 
$$\frac{1}{1-y} = 1 + y + y^2 + y^3 \dots$$

You get an infinite series of $1 + y + y^2 + y^3 \dots$ onto infinity. You integrate both sides to get $$-\ln(1-y) = y + \frac{y^2}{2} + \frac{y^3}{3} + \frac{y^4}{4}\dots \text{ on to infinity }$$

Because they are equivalent functions, the constants of integration ($C$) cancel out on both sides. You want the denominators of the right hand side to match the denominators of the series $\frac{1}{n^2}$, so that you can solve the Basel problem. So you divide both sides by $y$ and integrate once more from $0$ to $1$ to get the series $$\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(1-y)}{y}dy= 1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16\dots$$ You reverse the bounds of integration to account for the negative sign from earlier, and you get $$\int_1^0\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}dy= 1 + 1/4 + 1/9 + 1/16\dots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

The same integral with reversed bounds is the negative answer.
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}dy= -\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks @AritraDas for the edits into mathjax, I'm not fluent yet.

Comment: Not at all a problem. I found the insight your answer offered, really helpful.